# Image Overlay with Text using javascript in Sharepoint referencing to a "List Library" (adjust frame size)

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

Below is my code for displaying images with text overlay (referencing from one of my list).

```
<style type="text/css">
.myFrame1 { position: relative; overflow: auto;   }
    .myFrame1 li { list-style: none; }
        .myFrame1 ul li { float: left; }
            .myFrame1 ul {margin-left: -40px;}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

         var List1 = "frame1"; // Name of the list that contains slides
         var ContentField1 = "HTML"; //Name of the Rich text field that has slide content
         var BackgroundImageField1 = "Picture"; //Name of the picture field to use as background image

         Frame1(List1,ContentField1,BackgroundImageField1);
     });


    function Frame1(List1,ContentField1,BackgroundImageField1) {

        //query to retrieve all items
        var query = "<Query><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'></Value></Neq></Where></Query>";

        //return fields for slide content and background picture
        var camlViewFields = "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='"+ContentField1+"' /><FieldRef Name='"+BackgroundImageField1+"' /></ViewFields>";

        $().SPServices({
             operation: "GetListItems",
             async: true,
             listName: List1,
             CAMLViewFields: camlViewFields,
             CAMLQuery: query,
             completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                  $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                  var Content1 = ($(this).attr("ows_"+ContentField1));
                  var picture = $(this).attr("ows_"+BackgroundImageField1)==undefined?"":$(this).attr("ows_"+BackgroundImageField1).split(",")[0];
                  $("#Frame1").append("<li style=\"background-image: url('"+picture +"');\">"+Content1+"</li>");

             }); // end completefunc

           }
        }); // end SPServices call
    }
</script>

<div class="myFrame1"><ul id='Frame1'></ul></div>
```

- Note: This is one of the code I have downloaded from the internet and modified.

Basically, I need help on how to set the "frame size" as currently, the image size depends on the text content (HTML field) I am inputting.

-- For other's sake, the LIST contains below field:

- (1) Picture - html/picture (picture)
- (2) HTML - multiline text

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I just have to add the attributes in CSS as below.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .myFrame1 { position: relative; overflow: auto; }
    .myFrame1 li { list-style: none; height:250px; width:375px}
    .myFrame1 ul li { float: left; }
    .myFrame1 ul {margin-left: -40px;}      
</style>
```

This will do the trick. Hope this can help someone.